# Angular directive on Firefox

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I m having a strange problem with my directive on Firefox. My directive is simply for limiting the user input and it works on Chrome as how it supposed to be. But on Firefox, when the user enters input and it reaches its limit, you cant delete the number anymore.. the backspace locks somehow or any keys doesnt work.
For Example : 
when the user tries to enter more than 999 the keyboard locks but you can still delete the number on chrome. But in Firefox you cant delete, or press any number .
Any ideas ?

```
.directive("limitTo", [function() {
    return {
        restrict: "A",
        link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
            var limit = parseInt(attrs.limitTo);
            angular.element(elem).on("keypress", function() {
                if (this.value.length == limit){
                    return false;
                }
            });
        }
    };
}]);
```

Element :

```
 input limit-to="3" type="number" name="performance" class="typo-xl-l input-power">
```

Comment: Have you thought about using `input` Event instead? One can insert data with mouse, for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that you should be using event.preventDefault() instead of simply returning false in your event handler .. and you can check for specific key codes (for example, backspace is 8);

```
.directive("limitTo", [function() {
    return {
        restrict: "A",
        link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
            var limit = parseInt(attrs.limitTo);

            //backspace, up arrow, down arrow, delete... gets complicated quickly. 
            // you'll probably want more than these
            var allowedKeys = [8, 38, 40, 46];

            angular.element(elem).on("keypress", function(event) {
                var key = event.which || event.keyCode;
                if (this.value.length === limit && allowedKeys.indexOf(key) < 0 ){
                    event.preventDefault();
                }
            });
        }
    };
  }]);
```

A fiddle @ http://jsfiddle.net/o6gcyLjk/18/

You can additionally use the min and max properties on the input control to restrict the number range... BUT the user can still copy & paste to get the input in a state that you don't want.

I would probably recommend against this approach in general and use something like validation instead, warning the user of invalid input rather than trying too hard to prevent them..

Comment: "preventing the user from deleting characters once there are 3" thats my problem. In chrome it is not a problem but in firefox user cant delete when he enters 3 charachters

Comment: If you try on Chrome, deleting after 3 character is working with your fiddle but if you try in firefox, you cant delete.. try your fiddle link on both browsers pls..